# I need a regex to search in visual studio code for words starting with a specific string followed by letters that vary but exclude 3 specific cases

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I need to search within my project, all words starting with the string "use" followed by any uppercase letter and other than these three cases:

- useRef
- useEffect
- useState

Valid searches would be:

- useExample
- useTest
- useWhatever

And invalid searches:

- usefoo
- usebar

In addition to the 3 strings mentioned above.

This is as far as I've managed to go, but in vscode it seems to have a different behavior than any regular expression checker and I don't really know where to go from here:

```
^(?!useRef)(use.*)
```

Comment: `^(?!(useRef|useEffect|useState))use[A-Z].*` ? See: [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IySMSf/1)

Comment: Try `\b(use[A-Z]\w*)\b`

Comment: I see you have checked in 2 hours after  I posted the answer. Is it that bad? I think it does what you asked for, I provided the explanation and the demo.

Comment: @Theo I think [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/U0KtS4/2) does not take into account the exclusions listed at the top of the question, I addressed them in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259514/3832970).

Comment: @MaciejLos  I wonder if there are any serious issues with my solution below. Do you think the answer is so bad that it should be removed? There is a delete vote cast, that's why I am asking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah... totally missed that!

Comment: Hi Pablo, did my answer work for you? If not, please drop a comment below the answer to explain what issue you are having when using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```js
\buse(?!(?:Ref|Effect|State)\b)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b
```

See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/U0KtS4/1).

*Pattern details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `use` - a `use` string
- `(?!(?:Ref|Effect|State)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `Ref`, `Effect` or `State` substrings followed with a word boundary immediately to the right of the current location
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - any zero or more ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cbuse(%3F!(%3F%3ARef%7CEffect%7CState)%5Cb)%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D*%5Cb):

[image]